# incorrect parameter in FORMAT function

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to use this query in mysql database:

```
SELECT FORMAT(value, 2, 'de_de') FROM table ORDER BY value DESC
```

to have currency in european format (###,###.##).
But i get this error:

```
 #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FORMAT'
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Locale should be de_DE

Comment: yes, my fault... is 'de_DE' and i get the error

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(1114411, 1,1) ;
SELECT FORMAT(value,1,1) FROM table ORDER BY value DESC
```

Try above code.
Hope this will helps.

Comment: the above code works, but in this case i had currency in ###,###.## instead of ###.###,##

Comment: @Vardar I didn't get what you exactly want to say.